# Default Visual Studio 2010 and 2008 font

Tags: visual-studio, fonts

What is the default font (and its size) in the Visual Studio 2010 and 2008 editor?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2008 the default font is Courier New (size 10) but in Visual Studio 2010 the default font is Consolas (size 10).

Answer (score 19):

You can see what it's set to in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors.

My Visual Studio 2010 is set to Consolas 10 as the default Text Editor setting.

Answer (score 7):

The default font also depends on the language version of Visual Studio and the language of the operating system or the system locale. For example English VS 2008 on Japanese Windows defaults to MS Gothic.

Answer (score 6):

In VS2012 it can be Segoe UI size 10 also.

Comment: Yep thanks, this is the default font for "Environment Font" setting, as opposed to other answers referring to the "Text Editor" font.

Comment: Same in VS2013 and presumably VS2015

Answer (score 5):

It's Consolas Size 10 For My Visual Studio!

C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Conio.h"
using namespace std;

void main(){
int num1;
cout << "What's your favourite number:   ";
cin >> num1;
cout << endl;
cout << "Cool!" << num1 << " is my favourite number too!" << endl;
_getch();

}
```